# Pointer to class data member having inherited type

Tags: c++, c++11

I'd like to use a pointer to a class data member that has an inherited type. The code is pretty straightforward, I have an object (A) with a data member which class (Integer) inherits another class (Type), and I'd like to create a pointer to this data member using the parent class (Type*) instead of the base class (Integer) :

```
class Type
{
public:
    Type() {}
};

class Integer : public Type
{
public:
    Integer() : Type() {}
    int value;
};

class A
{
public:
    A() { p_value.value = 0; };
    Integer p_value;
};

int main()
{
    Type* aType = &A::p_value;
    return 0;
}
```

[the code on ideone](http://ideone.com/WBlfmy)

I have a compilation error:

```
error line: Type* aType = &A::p_value;
error: cannot convert 'Integer A::*' to 'Type*' in initialization
```

After a lot of fiddling with the code I couldn't make it work, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Why wd u want to typecast an integer pointer type to a pointer of type class?

Comment: Because `A` is a *class* and not an *object*. If you do e.g. `A myA; Type* aType = &myA.p_value;` it will work.

Comment: Ok it works but that doesn't explain why I can't do what I originally wanted. Why is it that you can't use the base type before the instantiation. The compiler already knows that Integer will be inheriting Type right ? 

To get an idea of what I would have liked to achieve, you can look at  [this](http://ideone.com/IQaeFQ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically types of pointers aren't matching. `&A::p_value` is of type `A::*Integer` (or `Integer A::*` as compiler nicely states), while `Type*` is... just `Type*`.

Former (`A::*Integer`) is a pointer to member and can be used like this:

```
A a1;
A* a2 = new A; 
A::*Integer a_member = &A::p_value;
a1.*a_member = 1;
a1->*a_member = 2;
// now a.p_value == 1 a->p_value == 2
```

Meanwhile `Type*` is just pointer to `Type` object - since `Type` class hierarchy is separate from A class hierarchy no casting between classes make sense. And here you want to cast from pointer to member to pointer to class. You most likely wanted to to something like this:

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    Type* aType = &a.p_value;
    return 0;
}
```

Difference lies in what they do. Pointer to class will look up in memory beginning of your object, then use information about where in this object particular member/virtual function pointer lies, go there and return value.
We use them to obtain data or call virtual method basing on object's address.

In the other hand pointer to member only knows the difference between beginning of object's memory and sought data position. So you need to have both object's address and the delta to figure out location of the data:

```
(object_by_value).*(pointer_to_member);
(object_by_pointer)->*(pointer_to_member);
```

By the way they work you can understand that casting one into another will only produce garbage and compiler saves you from that mistake with a warning:

```
cannot convert 'Integer A::*' to 'Type*' in initialization
```

Comment: Ok, so I can't do what I want to do originally, but at least now I understand why. Thanks! I wasn't sure if the type of an instance was used at runtime (for virtual function calls etc...) or at compile time (which would have made possible what I wanted to do, maybe with a different syntax).

Comment: Giving some thoughts: maybe what you wanted is to have virtual function in your interface: `int ::Integer::get_p_value() = 0` and pointer to that member function: `int (Integer::*ptr) () = &Integer::get_p_value;` called like this: `(a_object.*ptr)()`. It would more be useful though if you interface have more function of the same signature to chose from.

Comment: Actually I managed to do what I wanted by creating lambda functions on the run. I do things like  `static std::function<Type*(A* obj)> A::getValue() { return [](A* obj) { return &obj->p_value; } }` and then I can do `valueGetterForA = A::getvalue(); valueGetterForA(&instanceOfA)->functionDeclaredInTypeClass()`. This allows me to save the valueGetterForA only once and I can reuse it for each instance of A that I create.